# Laravel - Send post data with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to send post data and retrieve them in the response.
I look online and found guzzle, so there is what I've done :

The controller part I wan't to call on route 'test' :

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    return $request->input('test');
}

public function sinistre(Client $client) {
    $request = $client->post(route('test') , [], [
        'form_params' => [
            'test' => 'edf'
        ]
    ]);

    $response = $request->send();

    dd($response);

    return "ok";
}
```

Version of guzzle : "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"

For now I only got a 500 error response.

Comment: can you share `dd(route('test'));`

Comment: "http://localhost/project/laravel/test"

Comment: do you have this endpoint ?

Comment: In web.php : Route::post('/test', 'HomeController@test')
        ->name('test');

Comment: I mean do you have an api response on this endpoint?

Comment: The endpoint is the test method above, do the endpoint need to send a specific response ?

Comment: not exactly sure but eventually you send a request to an endpoint it suppose return something. in the worst case on your endpoint you can log the request comes from api call

Answer (score 3):

Laravel requires a [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) to be sent along with the request as it is a post request, so you can either exclude it or get a new token by using `csrf_token()`

Optionally as per the demo, you can exclude URI's from needing it

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'test/*',
    ];
}
```

You would of course need to update the `$except` URI with yours.

Comment: If you turn debug mode to true, most errors such as 500's will show why they are occurring, so next time a problem happens, post the error you get '500 error' simply isn't enough, this was a shot in the dark ^_^

Comment: Now that the request work and provide a 200 status, do you know how I can retrieve the data ? ; Edit : That was all I got but I will try to provide more informations next time

Comment: @ThomasPetillot [Read the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#responses)